# Phoenix session not being deleted

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am writing authentication for a *Phoenix Elixir* app. I have a *Plug* in my *Browser Pipeline* that checks for the user_id in the session. If it exists I add the *User* to the conn:

router.ex

```
pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
    plug AccountMgr.Plugs.CheckSessionForUser
end
```

check_for_user_on_session.ex

```
def call(conn, _opts) do
    user_id = get_session(conn, :user_id)

    cond do
      user = user_id && Repo.get(User, user_id) ->
        assign(conn, :current_user, user)
      true ->
        assign(conn, :current_user, nil)
    end
end
```

In my *Login* function I add the user_id to the session if the credentials are correct:

```
cond do
      user && checkpw(password, user.password_hash) ->
        conn
        |> assign(:user, user)
        |> put_session(:user_id, user.id)
        |> configure_session(renew: true) 
        |> redirect(to: portfolio_path(conn, :index))
      user ->
        {:error, :unauthorised, conn}
      true ->
        dummy_checkpw() 
        {:error, :not_found, conn}
end
```

In my Logout function I am calling `configure_session (conn, drop: true)`.

```
def logout(conn, _params) do
    configure_session(conn, drop: true)
    redirect(conn, to: authentication_path(conn, :index))
end
```

I am using `IO.puts` to show the `user_id` on the session before and after I call the `configure_session` function and the `user_id` is still present.

I am also logging the user_id in the check_for_user_on_session.ex *Plug* and it also shows the user_id present when it is called after the redirect from the logout function.

I am not sure what I am missing but I am expecting that the session cookie would be destroyed after the logout function and a new one created for the next page load through the router and *Browser Pipeline*

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say you're using `IO.puts` to show the `user_id`, I think you need to check it with next request, not the present one

Comment: Thank's David, I have logged the same information on the Plug that checks for the session user_id (It is in the Browser Pipeline) and it exists for the redirect page load

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `logout` function has an error in it. It should be:

```
def logout(conn, _params) do
    configure_session(conn, drop: true)
    |> redirect(to: authentication_path(conn, :index))
end
```

In the `logout` function you wrote, you were calling `configure_session` but then you were not using the return value, so the instruction to drop the session was not passed on to the `redirect` call.

Comment: Thanks David ... that was driving me crazy